# CMake build Tensorflow C++ on Windows 10 Error : Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - failed

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, cmake

I want to build Tensorflow C++ on Windows 10 using CMake. However I cannot pass the COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED test, which resulting in failed building attempts. Here is my open issue on tf github repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24076, which has received no response thus why I am asking on stackoverflow and hopefully someone here can enlighten me. I am running out of ideas now. I have tried Python 3.5 and 3.6, visual studio 2017 and 2015. All with no success.

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Windows 10
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): source
- TensorFlow version: the latest version
- Python version: 3.6
- Bazel version (if compiling from source): I am using CMake
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): gcc 6.30
- CUDA/cuDNN version: Installing only the CPU version
- I am also using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.3, btw

**Describe the problem**
I am following the "Step by step Windows Build" from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake. However, at step 3, I can't seem to pass `Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED`, which resulting failed building process.

**Provide the exact sequence of commands / steps that you executed before running into the problem**

```
PS C:\Users\bw\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build> cmake .. -A x64 -Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release `
>> -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE='C:\Program Files\swigwin-3.0.12\swig.exe' `
>> -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe' `
>> -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs\python36.lib'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  Your current cmake generator is set to use 32 bit toolset architecture.
  This may cause "compiler out of heap space" errors when building.  Consider
  using the flag -Thost=x64 when running cmake.


-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27024.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27024.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed
-- Performing Test MSVC_OPENMP_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test MSVC_OPENMP_SUPPORT - Success
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/python.exe (found version "3.6.7")
-- Found PythonLibs: optimized;C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/libs/python36.lib;debug;C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/libs/python36_d.lib (found version "3.6.7")
-- Found SWIG: C:/Program Files/swigwin-3.0.12/swig.exe (found version "3.0.12")
CMake Error at tf_python.cmake:811 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:583 (include)


CMake Error at tf_python.cmake:812 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:583 (include)


CMake Error at tf_python.cmake:813 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:583 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/bw/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/bw/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

**Any other info / logs**

CMakeOutput.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fweyunxdbmxa1k/CMakeOutput.log?dl=0
CMakeError.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tucx0tl6346kdpd/CMakeError.log?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

The first line of the guide states:

> CMAKE build is deprecated for TensorFlow. Please use bazel to build TF for all platforms. For details, see the TensorFlow install guide.

Apparently you need to use a release version that is known to build correctly via CMAKE on Windows.  Probably should switch to the recommended build system if you want to build the latest code.

Looking at the CMakeLists.txt file for this project shows that `Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed` is the step where it checks if the compiler accepts the `-march=native` flag.  It doesn't, see this fix https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8724#issuecomment-289326917.

The actual errors are due to a scripting issue in `tf_python.cmake` that cannot properly parse one of the source files.  It seems to me that the issues are unrelated.

Comment: Thanks Fred! I have followed the link you posted, and replaced `-march=native` with `/arch:[AVX|AVX2]` in CMakeLists.txt, but still getting `Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed`. Am I doing anything wrong here? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again.